# Custom taxonomy multiples

Tags: custom-taxonomy

If I've registered a custom taxonomy called "Color" and a custom post type called "Product", is it possible to use that taxonomy twice? Essentially, I'd like to have a relationship that allows groupings of color so:

```
- Product
  - Interior (Color)
    - Black
    - Green
  - Exterior (Color)
    - Black
```

Essentially a slot for Color Types that would use the same Color taxonomy. Possible without distinct "Exterior Color" and "Interior Color" taxonomies?

Would love to avoid a plugin if possible.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just have a hierarchical taxonomy of `color` and under that construct it just like you have it? That way "Exterior Color" and "Interior Color" are just terms of the `color` taxonomy and you only have to have one.

Comment: @brianjohnhanna I tried that but wordpress displays "Black" and "Black" next to each other and removed from parent taxonomy when selected. Very confusing.